# Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '["foo", "bar"]' in this Zod example?

Tags: typescript, zod

I have [this Zod playground](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-qocdcn?file=index.ts), duplicated below. The goal is to create a `filter` property which takes a `path` of strings in its definition, and only allows that.

```
import { z } from 'zod';

type AS = Array<string>;

export const FilterTestBaseQuery = (path: Array<string>) =>
  z.object({
    type: z.enum(['test']),
    path: z
      .array(z.string())
      .refine(
        (array) =>
          array.length === path.length &&
          JSON.stringify(path) === JSON.stringify(array),
        {
          message: `Path is invalid`,
        }
      ),
  });

export const FilterBooleanBasicQuery = (path: Array<string>) =>
  FilterTestBaseQuery(path).merge(
    z.object({
      value: z.union([z.boolean(), z.null()]),
      test: z.enum(['=', '!=']),
    })
  );

export const FilterBooleanBasicArrayQuery = (path: Array<string>) =>
  FilterTestBaseQuery(path).merge(
    z.object({
      value: z.array(z.union([z.boolean(), z.null()])),
      test: z.enum(['in']),
    })
  );

export type FilterBooleanType<P extends AS> = FilterBooleanValueQueryType<P>;

export type FilterBooleanValueQueryType<P extends AS> =
  | FilterBooleanBasicQueryType<P>
  | FilterBooleanBasicArrayQueryType<P>;

export type FilterBooleanBasicQueryType<P extends AS> =
  FilterTestBaseQueryType<P> & {
    value: boolean | null;
    test: '=' | '!=';
  };

export type FilterBooleanBasicArrayQueryType<P extends AS> =
  FilterTestBaseQueryType<P> & {
    value: Array<boolean | null>;
    test: 'in';
  };

export type FilterTestBaseQueryType<P extends AS> = {
  type: 'test';
  path: P;
};

type AType = {
  filter: FilterBooleanBasicQueryType<['foo', 'bar']>;
};

const A: z.ZodType<AType> = z.object({
  filter: FilterBooleanBasicQuery(['foo', 'bar']),
});

console.log(A);
```

My real example is [much more complicated](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jggfie?file=index.ts,package.json), in trying to make a semi-robust filtering system for an API. So I tried to isolate out the main simple error, and from figuring that out I hope to figure out how to get the general system working.

It's weird, because locally I am getting one error:

```
Types of property 'path' are incompatible.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '["foo", "bar"]'.
    Target requires 2 element(s) but source may have fewer.ts(2322)
```

[image]

But on that StackBlitz playground, I am getting a different error:

```
Property 'type' is optional in type '{ path?: string[]; type?: "test"; value?: boolean; test?: "=" | "!="; }' but required in type 'FilterTestBaseQueryType<["foo", "bar"]>'.
```

Any ideas if this can be made to work? Not sure what main thing is going wrong yet, and it seems like this might potentially be overloading the TypeScript compiler perhaps?

### Update 1

Adding this to `tsconfig.json` makes it so the Playground has the same error as local:

```
"strictNullChecks": true,
"strict": true,
```

[It now says](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-qocdcn?file=index.ts,tsconfig.json):

```
Types of property 'path' are incompatible.
  Type 'string[]' is not assignable to type '["foo", "bar"]'.
```

### Update 2

If I change this `z.array(path)` to this:

```
export const FilterTestBaseQuery = (path: Array<string>) =>
  z.object({
    type: z.enum(['test']),
    path: z
      .array(
        path.map(({ text }) => {
          return z.object({
            text: z.enum([text]),
          })
        }),
      )
      .refine(
        array => array.length === path.length && _.isEqual(path, array),
        {
          message: `Path is invalid`,
        },
      ),
  })
```

I get a new error, so it has something to do with that:

[image]